# Можно ли автоматизировать процесс навигации в облачной версии 1С с помощью библиотеки Selenium в Python (клики по кнопкам)?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, 1с, автоматизация

Всем привет! Я - новичок в программировании. Изучаю библиотеку selenium с помощью python. Пытаюсь решить прикладную задачу для производства в части автоматизации процесса запроса данных в облачной 1С выгрузкой файлов и проведением ряда расчетов в Pandas.

Захожу как обычный пользователь со своими логином и паролем. Взаимодействие происходит через облачную виртуальную машину и "тонкого" клиента. Регистрация на сайте проходит нормально. Встал вопрос, как "ткнуть" в необходимую кнопку в уже открывшемся окне с 1С.
На первом этапе меня интересует кнопка "Склад и доставка" (дальше, думаю, будет по аналогии. Надо понять именно первый шаг). Код на скрине.

Пробовал искать по тексту, по классу, прописывать путь, менять пробелы на точки и пр. Не получается. Ошибка в неверно переданном аргументе.
Я неверно передаю аргументы в код:

```
button = driver.find_element('...', "***")
button.click()
```

Выглядит как просто отсутствие опыта с моей стороны. Вообще в целом не понимаю, "за что" тут надо зацепиться Селениумом (за класс, за путь, за текст). Если кто-то объяснит матчасть, как говорится, а не только поможет кодом, буду благодарен вдвойне.

```
from selenium import webdriver as wb
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from time import sleep
driver =wb.Chrome('/Users/***/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get("***")
sleep(5.0)
login = '***'
password = '***'
login_field = driver.find_element('id','userName')
login_field.send_keys(login)
password_field = driver.find_element('id','userPassword')
password_field.send_keys(password)
button = driver.find_element('id', "okButton")
button.click()
sleep(30.0)
```

До этого момента код работает. После этого происходит загрузка страницы из облачной 1С, и на этом этапе возникли проблемы с кодом.

HTML-код не влазит по объему симовлов. Сам текст "Склад и дставка" лежит вот тут:

```
<div class="tooltip absolute noselect" style="top: -100000px; width: auto; left: 124px;"><div class="m-4">Склад и доставка</div><div class="flex flex-ai-center m-4" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Справка</a><div class="m-2"></div><a href="#" class="ico" title="Открыть справку"><svg><use xlink:href="#svg_about" href="#svg_about"></use></svg></a></div></div>
```

Структура и уровни HTML-кода видны вот тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте! Добавьте в свой вопрос свой Python код, который у вас не работает и html код вашей страницы.

Comment: Просьба подробнее описать процесс: со своего компа обращаешься к 1С в облаке ? или это всё происходит на сервере 1С ? либо на виртуалке с доступом к серверу 1С ? есть ли доступ к конфигурации 1С ?

Comment: Захожу в 1 с как обычный пользователб под своим логином и паролем. Есть типовые задачи, которые я как испдир отслеживаю. Хотелось бы их автоматизировать. Зайти в нет, открыть 1С, ввести логин и пароль, выбрать отчет, выбрать даты, настроить параметры - выглядит как операции, которые можно прописать в коде. 
Взаимодействие происходит через виртуальную машину и "тонкого" клиента.
Участок обработки полученных из 1С документов в пандасе я прописал. Считает, выгружает в Эксель, пересылает, куда надо. А вот с 1С воткнулся. И пока никуда сдвинутся не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта решения:

1. На виртуальной машине где заходим в 1С, устанавливаем AutoIT; Это скриптовый язык, который позволяет запустить прогу/активировать окно, затем сгенерировать клик мышью в указанную область и так далее (сделать паузу); Сможем полностью имитировать работу юзера 1С (делая клики в нужную область экрана)
2. Написать обработку в 1С (нужен доступ к конфигуратору, возможно Полные права); На виртуальной машине где заходим в 1С, делаем ярлык в котором 1С запускается и выполняет нашу обработку после старта; Внутри 1С-обработки выполняем всё что нужно; Запуск ярлыка можем прописать в шедулере по расписанию;

Comment: Вопрос именно в использовании Селениума. Возможно ли это?.. по моей логике, это все тот же html-код на странице, значит, Селениум может и должен решить эту проблему. Тем более практика кликов через забор div'ов существует.

Comment: по Селениуму подсказать не могу; но гуглится полно ссылок: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69847454/selenium-cant-find-the-div-element-to-click

Comment: Да, ссылок много. Я тоже перечитал много материала. К сожалению, во многих материалах чуть более очевидные примеры (как, например, поиск по id  и пр.), которые к решению моего вопроса не привели.